# List of Devices Registered on GCM

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I am using  **Google Cloud Messaging APIs**.

On the server side i want to get the list of all the devices that are registered on a **Project ID** that is given by Google Cloud Messaging .So could i get the all list of the devices so that i can store all of them into the database.Please provide me the suggestion on this how can we do this.Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be registering a device on client side by getting the `registration ID`. So, as soon the user's device gets a registration ID, send the ID to your own server. At your server, you can store all the `registration ID`'s this way. You'll have the list of all the devices that are registered to your `SENDER ID`.

Comment: Are you asking that is it the best way? I am not sure of any one way. This used to be the way before the latest API came out in August. Still this is one way of storing the ID's. For latest update you might want to read http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html .

Comment: see i want to store the id of the device registered to my project .after that i want to send them the notification. For this what u think what we can do ??

Comment: Yes. For that only I answered. There is one client side code and one server side. The client side code is responsible for getting the `registration ID` from the Google GCM server, storing it locally and sending it to your 3rd party server( which you will implement). The server side code which you'll implement on your 3rd party server is responsible for storing the ID's. Then using those ID's the 3rd party server has to request the Google GCM server to send a Push Notification to those ID's. Does it makes sense? :)